# Insert into MySQL Table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-insert

I am having some trouble making a simple form to insert data into a MySQL table. I keep getting this SQL error:

> "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'stock ('ItemNumber', 'Stock') VALUES ('#4','3'')' at line 1"

My **HTML** for the form is:

```
    <form action="database.php" method="post">
    Item Number: <input type="text" name="ItemNumber">
    Stock: <input type="text" name="Stock">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

And the **PHP** is:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","inventory");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
     $sql = "INSERT INTO current stock ('ItemNumber', 'Stock')
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[ItemNumber]','$_POST[Stock]'')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "1 record added";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Your web page is wide open to SQL injections. Don't code like this. Instead use stored procedures, parameterized SQL commands and forbid user from inputting special characters...

Comment: I would also avoid the use of space character in a table or field name.

Comment: I know this is an old question but Bill Karwin has the best answer here.  The other answers are insecure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

you should not  use quotes of parameter around POST . and you should use them inside POST

```
       $sql = "INSERT INTO `current stock` (ItemNumber, Stock)
           VALUES
         ('".$_POST['ItemNumber']."', '".$_POST['Stock']."' )";
```

you should escape your variables before you insert them to mysql like that

- Note that the example does not call `mysqli_real_escape_string`. You would only need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you were embedding the string directly in the query, but I would advise you to never do this. Always use parameters whenever possible.

Comment: Please don't give bad examples with SQL-injections, especially to beginners that still have problems with the syntax....

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra quote and you need ticks around your table name as it contains a space.

```
INSERT INTO current stock ('ItemNumber', 'Stock')
VALUES
('$_POST[ItemNumber]','$_POST[Stock]'')";
```

should be:

```
INSERT INTO `current stock` (`ItemNumber`, `Stock`)
VALUES
('$_POST[ItemNumber]','$_POST[Stock]')";
```

FYI, you also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Answer (score 0):

```
?php
  $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","inventory")
  or die("not connected".mysqli_connect_error());
  if(isset($_POST['submit']{
    $ItemNumber=$_POST['ItemNumber'];
    $Stock=$_POST['Stock'];
    $sql="insert into current stock(ItemNumber,Stock) values('$ItemNumber','$Stock')";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($query){
      echo"1 row inserted";
    }else{
      echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvY1aw5cJUw&list=PLImJFXvEG-10ggD_nBGKcvyaDeclQ8fOu&index=7

Comment: If this is meant as part of [your existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43278095/794749), add this to your existing answer and add an explanation. Otherwise this isn't really a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn to use parameter binding. You are creating code with security vulnerabilities.

Here's how to do your code in mysqli:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO current stock (ItemNumber, Stock) VALUES (?, ?)";

if (!($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql))) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

if (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_POST[ItemNumber], $_POST[Stock])) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}

if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}
```

It's easier to use bound parameters than to get all confused with quotes-within-quotes.

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="database.php" method="post">
   Item Number: <input type="text" name="ItemNumber">
   Stock: <input type="text" name="Stock">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>`
```