# creating multiple uploads using the same username

Tags: php

how can the user create multiple uploads using the same username i don't know what to do please guide me. the idea is this the user creates a custom shirt using div then when the user is done the div is converted into an image the user manually upload the image with some information that he/she types like the title of the product, keywords and description of the product image the the user created. right now what happens is that the user is only allowed to upload one image and one title etc. how can i allow the user to create multiple uploads using the same username/email? i want to make this as simple as possible without making multiple tables in DB i only have basic code that i use to upload

```html
<?php
 require_once("configur.php");
 
$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost,password, user);

$query='UPDATE shirt_table SET   images4="'.$_FILES['file5']['name'].'", images5="'.$_FILES['file6']['name'].'", images6="'.$_FILES['file7']['name'].'", images7="'.$_FILES['file8']['name'].'"
WHERE email= "'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are doing UPDATE on the table based on the email.  This will always change that single row.  You need to use INSERT to create a new row for each shirt design for that user / email.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138561/insert-into-mysql-table-php?source=1 not exactly the same question but gives an example of insert